# Can the NPPL exams now be taken online?

Tags: ppl, uk, exams

I can see that the CAA portal now offers PPL theory exams online from [this article](https://www.caa.co.uk/News/CAA-launches-new-online-PPL-e-Exams-system/) and by signing into the portal:
[image]

Can the 5 exams required for an NPPL(m) now be taken online?

Answer (score 1):

They are taken on a computer, but at the ATO/DTO office